# How to access a field inside a rowtype in a Postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Table `FOO` has columns `A and B`

Table `BAR` has columns `X, Y and Z`.

I have a function `func` that returns a ROWTYPE of table `BAR`

```
FUNCTION func(arg1, arg2) RETURNS BAR
```

I want to do something like this

```
select A,B, func(A,B).X from FOO;
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
 syntax error at or near "."
```

However, if I do not not use `.<column_name>` after the function, then it serializes the entire RECORD returned by the function as text.

How do I  choose just `X` instead of all constituent fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

You need to enclose the function call in brackets and then use a `.`

This fails:

<s>`select A,B, func(A,B).X from FOO;`</s>

This works:

```
select A,B, (func(A,B)).X from FOO;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html

Comment: This chapter also explains it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION